# Location zero in Android Maps API

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

My code create a route between two points on the map in the coordinates I'm trying to get past the coodernada from my current location to the fromPosition, using the low code. But he is giving 0,0 in Log.i;

```
double lat;
double lng;

LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(-5.082434, -42.807364);
```

But I need the co-penned fromPosition to be my current position.

Thank you for any help.

```
public class MapsActivity2 extends FragmentActivity  {

private GoogleMap map;

double lat;
double lng;

LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(-5.082434, -42.807364);

ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint;
Marker mPositionMarker;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
    initializeMap();

    Log.i("david", "LATLNG= " + fromPosition);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    long tempo = 1000; //5 minutos
    float distancia = 1; // 30 metros

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER , tempo , distancia,  new LocationListener() {


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Habilitado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Desabilitado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location == null)
                return;

             map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

             lat = location.getLatitude();
             lng = location.getLongitude();


            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new
                    LatLng(lat, lng), 16));

            if (mPositionMarker == null) {

                mPositionMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .flat(true)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.car))
                        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                        .getLongitude())));
            }


            animateMarker(mPositionMarker, location); // Helper method for smooth
            // animation

            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));

        }


        public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final Location location) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            final LatLng startLatLng = marker.getPosition();
            final double startRotation = marker.getRotation();
            final long duration = 500;

            final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                    float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                            / duration);

                    double lng = t * location.getLongitude() + (1 - t)
                            * startLatLng.longitude;
                    double lat = t * location.getLatitude() + (1 - t)
                            * startLatLng.latitude;

                    float rotation = (float) (t * location.getBearing() + (1 - t)
                            * startRotation);

                    marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                    marker.setRotation(rotation);

                    if (t < 1.0) {
                        // Post again 16ms later.
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, null);
}

private void initializeMap() {
    if (map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();



        new WebserviceTask(this).execute();





    }
}


public void setDirectionPoints(ArrayList<LatLng> result) {
    directionPoint = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    directionPoint = result;
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initializeMap();
}

public class WebserviceTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<LatLng>> {
    MapsActivity2 mContext;
    PolylineOptions rectline;

    public WebserviceTask(MapsActivity2 context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<LatLng> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            rectline = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(Color.BLUE);

            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
                rectline.add(result.get(i));
            map.addPolyline(rectline);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<LatLng> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
        Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition,
                GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
        if (doc != null) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);

            rectline = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(Color.RED);

            for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++)
                rectline.add(directionPoint.get(i));

            return directionPoint;
        } else
            return null;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: @Daniel Nugent This is a duplicate friend question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /**Implement the code Snipet in your initializeMap() Method***/


 private void initializeMap() 
 {
    if (map == null) 
    {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        new WebserviceTask(this).execute();

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(fromPosition, 10));

       map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Marker Location")
            .snippet("Marker Location Address")
            .position(fromPosition));

    map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Display my current location this code already does this. That LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng (-5.072091, -42.819174); Be my current coodernas.

Comment: So you want me to help you in displaying  the route between fromPosition and toPosition.

Comment: The way the code is already displaying the route. More with the coaxing of fixed output, I need to pick up my GPS coordinate and arrow on the fromPosition.

Comment: I changed my question with code that I tried to update and it did not work.